# A homework exercise about database architectures

Tags: database

I don't need any answers I am simply looking for a breakdown in laymans terms of what this essay is asking for.

I have done part A its very straight forward however I am not sure what he means when he refers to Applications. Part d is also simple enough.

My main problem is I am struggling with the context of part b, c. For whatever reason the question (perhaps the wording) is going straight over my head. If anyone could simply breakdown and explain part b and c I would very grateful, I can finish this essay up.

Any links would be an added bonus but certainly not expected thank guys.

a)  Discuss the 2-tier architecture and the 3-tier architecture of database     application processing in terms of architectural layout, applications,  performance, security, advantages and disadvantages of such environment.                                              (40 marks)

b)  Discuss the software environment of both architectures including the use of     high level and mark-up languages, servers with interfaces on different  platforms, communication links and tools used.            (20 marks)

c)  Discuss future planned developments in these two architectures environments     in terms of hardware configuration, software utilisation and applications areas.                                          (20 marks)

d)  Provide a conclusion of the report indicating a summary of your investigation   by arguing the suitability of architectural layout software environment and     application areas with reasoning.                     (10 marks)

Comment: Did you just copy-pasted your homework?

Comment: At least he was honest about it being homework problem.

Comment: In the context of my question I needed to copy paste it as its part b, part c I am not understanding. I dont want an oppinion on the answer, that is for me to do, simply an explanation of what the question is asking of me.

Comment: Okay guys if anyone is ever tasked with somthing similar to this coursework. Part A refers to a comparison of the Architecture layouts of 2 and 3 tiered architecture, discuss the layers of each and the performance and security issues with each.

Part B is asking to discuss HTML SQL and other languages used to communicate each architecture such as a Java Application using JDBC, at this point I discussed the SQL Api etc..

Part C I discussed the the layout of the client and servers in hardware terms, API distirbuted database etc...

I hope this may help someone in the future.

Si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys if anyone is ever tasked with somthing similar to this coursework. Part A refers to a comparison of the Architecture layouts of 2 and 3 tiered architecture, discuss the layers of each and the performance and security issues with each. Part B is asking to discuss HTML SQL and other languages used to communicate each architecture such as a Java Application using JDBC, at this point I discussed the SQL Api etc.. Part C I discussed the the layout of the client and servers in hardware terms, API distirbuted database etc... I hope this may help someone in the future. Si